# Including Snippets and Templates with conditions in Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid, liquid-layout

I'm trying to include some snippets and templates on a product page based on the product type. However, liquid doens't seem to generate snippets conditionally.

An example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
{% if product.type == 'shoes' %}
   {% include 'shoes-template' %}
{% else %}
   {% include 'other-template' %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: There is something. Conditional `include` works. I use it at many places. Can you share any other relevant code? `shoes-template` and `other-template` also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have many product types, instead of using multiple `if` and `else if`, you can use an array and a `contains`. 
You can also verify if a template exist by performing a `capture` and looking for the string "Liquid error".

```
{% assign types = "shoes, shirts, pants" | split:", " %}
{% if types contains product.type %}
    {% assign snip = product.type | append:"-template" %}
{% else %}
    {% assign snip = "other-template" %}
{% endif %}

{% capture snip_content %}{% include snip %}{% endcapture %}
{% unless snip_content contains "Liquid error" %}
    {% include snip %}
{% endunless %}
```

Comment: That's a round about way. I'm not sure if it is efficient. Also `["shoes","shirts"]` doesn't signify an array in liquid code.

Comment: I fixed the array. If you have many product types, this is more efficient than a long `if, else if, else if, ...` as long as you are consistent with your template filenames.